# mutate to NA based on condition

Tags: r, date, na, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two date columns (date_a and date_b) and one factor column (c) [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5QlQ.png)

Now I'd like to replace all values in date_a by NA, if date_b is not NA (or if c is not NA). I've tried for the past hours, and the closest I get is this code:

```
df<- df %>% 
  mutate(date_a = case_when(
    is.na(c) == FALSE ~ NA
  ))
```

But this replaces the entire column date_a by NA.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not add data as images. We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` to define a conditional value.

The first argument of `ifelse` is the condition. In this case we want `!is.na(date_b)|!is.na(c)` to indicate if either is not `NA`. The second argument is what we want if the first argument evaluates `TRUE`. In this case, can just return that value of `date_a`.  The final argument is what we want if argument 1 evaluates `FALSE`, and we need to use `NA_character` because the rest of the column is character.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date_a = ifelse(!is.na(date_b)|!is.na(c),NA_character_,date_a))
      date_a     date_b     c
1 2012-10-11       <NA>  <NA>
2       <NA> 2016-01-08 house
3 2019-12-19       <NA>  <NA>
4 2019-06-14       <NA>  <NA>
5 2014-04-22       <NA>  <NA>
6       <NA> 2017-08-03  boat
7 2018-11-20       <NA>  <NA>
8       <NA> 2017-06-16  boat
9       <NA> 2016-03-17  boat
```

The same can be done with `case_when`, but it is unnecessary when there is only one condition:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(date_a = case_when(!is.na(date_b)|!is.na(c) ~ NA_character_,
          TRUE ~ date_a))
```

If you run into trouble that your columns are of a different class (as @akrun pointed out in the comments), such as `Date`, you could try something like this:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(date_a = case_when(!is.na(date_b)|!is.na(c) ~ as.Date(NA), TRUE ~ date_a))
```

Sample Data:

```
df <- structure(list(date_a = c("2012-10-11", "2016-01-08", "2019-12-19", 
"2019-06-14", "2014-04-22", "2017-08-03", "2018-11-20", "2017-06-16", 
"2016-03-17"), date_b = c(NA, "2016-01-08", NA, NA, NA, "2017-08-03", 
NA, "2017-06-16", "2016-03-17"), c = c(NA, "house", NA, NA, NA, 
"boat", NA, "boat", "boat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: @akrun good point, is there a hint in that screenshot that suggests the type is date?

Comment: Thanks guys, the date columns are indeed of class Date. So I tried the 3rd option and it worked perfectly. Thanks heaps guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R one-liner with `is.na<-`.
The test data set is the data set in [Ian Campbell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544216/8245406).

```
is.na(df$date_a) <- with(df, !(is.na(date_b) | is.na(c)))

df
#      date_a     date_b     c
#1 2012-10-11       <NA>  <NA>
#2       <NA> 2016-01-08 house
#3 2019-12-19       <NA>  <NA>
#4 2019-06-14       <NA>  <NA>
#5 2014-04-22       <NA>  <NA>
#6       <NA> 2017-08-03  boat
#7 2018-11-20       <NA>  <NA>
#8       <NA> 2017-06-16  boat
#9       <NA> 2016-03-17  boat
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the other condition as well:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(date_a = case_when(
    is.na(c) ~ NA_character_,
    TRUE     ~ c
  ))
```